# explain this code

Tags: c, avr

can anyone please explain this code?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/signal.h>

char n = 0;
char FLAG =0x00;
char FLAG2 =0x00;

char RST=0x00;
unsigned char minutes_save [20];
unsigned char seconds_save [20];
int seconds, minutes, shift, count;




void init(void)
{

    DDRB = 0xff;
    DDRA  =0xff;
    MCUCR = 0x0F;
    GICR = 0xC0;
    TCCR2 = 0x05;
    ASSR = 0x08;
    TCNT2 = 0x00;
    sei();
}


SIGNAL(SIG_INTERRUPT0)

{   

    if (FLAG == 0x00)
        TIMSK = 0x40;

    if (FLAG == 0x01)
        TIMSK = 0x00;

    FLAG = FLAG ^ 1;

}
```

Comment: No - most people do not have access to the relevant headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the program receives an interrupt signal, it modifies the value of `TIMSK` to be 0x40 (64 in decimal) or 0x00 (0 in decimal) depending upon whether `FLAG` is currently set to be 0 or 1, and then it inverts the value of `FLAG` by performing a bitwise XOR operation with 1.

As for the rest of the code (the `init()` function, the other variables being declared, and the `sei()` function), there is not enough context provided by the code to determine what exactly it is doing/trying to do.

This page might be helpful:  http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/PDETAIL.html

It appears your code is setting register values on an ATMEL AVR embedded processor.

Comment: `sei()` is probably the interrupt enable call (usually translates to an atomic instruction).